# No valid exports main found on npm (tailwind css)

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, npm, tailwind-css, npx

[image]i am learning tailwind css and in tutorial they write a command like this `npx tailwindcss-cli build css/tailwind.css -o build/tailwind.css`
and it build a different folder name "tailwind.css" in same directory
but in my case it gives a error

```
No valid exports main found for 'C:\Users\HHH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\4952\node_modules\tailwindcss-cli\node_modules\postcss'
```

I don't have any idea what it means and whats wrong with the setup.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution.
Just install the current node.js and reinstall the specific version.
[download here](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v13.11.0/)

After that install it and everything works fine.
Note: It works in when you follow the tailwindcss cli method.
[follow first part of video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0Q8SQSCoZg&list=PLu0W_9lII9ahwFDuExCpPFHAK829Wto2O&index=2)